# Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Homepage)"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Everything was fine until I updated some of environments (npm, node, expo-cli etc.). After that I tried to run my application and I got an error. I don't understand why the app throw this error because it was running perfectly before.

This is my error:

`Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Homepage)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(Homepage) in connect options.`

This is my `App.js` file:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={createStore(reducer, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))}>
        <Router />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
```

This is my `Homepage.js` file:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchGames })(Homepage);
```

Comment: What does your reducer look like? Where is initial state come from?

Comment: This is unnecessary thing.